# Problemas ao executar comandos no CMD com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Não estou conseguindo executar (ou obter o resultado) de comandos executados no Windows pelo Python.
Eu peguei um exemplos de código que vi em vário sites e respostas no SO, mas nenhum funcionou bem pra mim.

```
import subprocess

# Exception: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
stdout = subprocess.check_call(['dir'])

proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True, bufsize = 1)    
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('dir c:\\'.encode())
# Retorna sempre a mesma coisa
print(stdout)
```

Único retorno que tenho do print acima é sempre isso:

> b'Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]\r\n(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\Users\Daniel>More? '

Já tentei executar como administrador. Já tentei em outra máquina. Já tentei vários comandos diferentes, `dir` é só um exemplo. Já tentei mudar os parâmetros do `Popen`.

Obs: O `.encode()` que coloquei no argumento do `communicate()` foi por minha conta (também já tentei com `b''`). Pelo que pesquisei, recentemente o Python alterou o padrão de entrada de dados de diversas funções nativas de string para bytes, apesar que todos exemplos que eu achava deste método estavam usando string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exception: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Essa exceção é lançada porque o sistema não reconhece `dir` como um executável, você deve passá-lo como argumento ao *cmd.exe*.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(["cmd.exe", "dir"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:                             
    print ("error code: {}".format(e.returncode))
```

Segundo a documentação do método [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

> Executa o comando com argumentos. Aguarda até que o comando seja
>   concluído. Se o código de retorno foi zero, então continua, caso
>   contrário a exceção `CalledProcessError` é lançada.

Talvez o método que você esteja procurando é o [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) que executa o comando e retorna a saída:

```
try:
    saida = subprocess.check_output(["cmd.exe", "/C", "dir"]) 
    print (saida)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:                            
    print ("error code: {}".format(e.returncode))
```

Se preferir usar o [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
pop = subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe", "/C", "dir"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
saida, erros = pop.communicate()

print (saida, erros)
```